# ADB - VirtualBox connection

Tags: android, eclipse, adb, virtualbox

I've trying to connect ADB and a VirtualBox Android device. I've followed all possible tutorial on the web but it's still not working.
What i've done :

- dl Adroidx86 from androidx86.org
- intall it on VirtualBox
- configure network with correct access mode (bridge) and card (PC-net Fast III)
- type `netcfg` in the virtual machine terminal and get 192.168.1.12 for IP address (static)
- type `adb kill-server` on the host machine
- type `adb connect 192.168.1.12` on the host machine

And get the error unable to connect to 192.168.1.12:5555.
I'm running windows 7 as OS.

Have you any idea why ?? How to know the port of the device to connect ?
Thank you !

Answer (score 20):

I had the same issue once, did you check your VM network configuration?
My VM network is configured like this: NAT with mode, deny, adapter as PCnet-FAST III and I add this rule to forward.

[image]

Always the most sneaky part is the network configuration of the VM, try with this one. If you still have issues check this tutorials:
[Speeding up Android development with Android-x86 and VirtualBox](http://web.archive.org/web/20121115204402/http://brunocosta.com/blog/2011/11/02/speeding-up-android-development-with-android-x86-and-virtualbox/)

Comment: Thanks for answering, i've now an android device... An not that kind of problem any more ! But yes, I think that the problem was something like that.

Answer (score 4):

I think now it should be automatic. But you can try the old way to connect Android x86 by doing this:

- Go to the console by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>
- execute this commands:

> su
>
> setprop service.adb.tcp.port 5555
>
> stop adbd
>
> start adbd
>
> Go back to Android: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>
>
> After that try in your Windows host to connect via adb and see if it worked.

Comment: Thanks for trying but I still have the same error... Even after an adb kill-server. Any other idea ?

Comment: Just to be sure.. are you in the same network with your host (Windows)? 192.168.1.XXX?

Comment: My host, when I type ipconfig, gives me the following :  IPv4: 10.68.86.20. Does it mean that i've to configure my VM to be n the same network (10.68.86.XXX) ?

Comment: I've try with 10.68.86.21... Still the same result.

Answer (score 2):

First do the **Port Forwarding** settings like this

[image: VirtualBox Network Setting]

Then run this **Command**: `adb connect 127.0.0.1`

[image: adb connect]

Answer (score 1):

What I did is to use a bridged network connection, then connect the adb on the guest OS with the phone ip address, found in settings->about phone. For example

```
adb connect 192.168.0.222:5555
```