# How do I get the Ip address of the Android x86 machine from outside VirtualBox/Android console?

Tags: adb, virtualbox, android-x86

How do I get the Ip address of the Android x86 machine from outside Virtualbox/Android console?

I am currently running Android x86 in Virtualbox. Instead of opening the Android console to run`ifconfig` to get the Ip address, I want to be able to get the Ip address of the machine from outside the Android console?
I have tried various other methods such as

```
VBoxManage guestproperty get <vm_name> "VirtualBox/GuestInfo/Net/0/V4/IP"
```

However, no value is set!

I saw other post that recommends setting static Ip address for the machines, but wouldn't you need to reconfigure them again when you switch to a different network? (not very sure about this)

I need the IP address to use adb to connect to the android host machine.
Are there any idea or workaround for this?

Comment: Did you try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15251024/adb-virtualbox-connection?

Comment: ah ok, was stuck at first as I couldn't get any other network config going for android other than bridged adapter but turning off cloudflare seemed to allow android to have network using NAT .
After getting it to work on NAT, reading the given post again made me realise port forwarding might be a solution. I am using the command 'VBoxManage modifyvm Android --natpf1 "net1,tcp,,port,,5555" ' to auto assign ports instead.